# Phonegap/Cordova ios External Links inside iframe not opening in safari

Tags: ios, cordova

I know we can use inapp browser for opening external links in the app. But I am talking about the links with in iframe, inapp browser solution doesn't work for links inside iframe. I somehow need to open external links from iframe in safari browser of iPhone. Is there a workaround for this ?

Following is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.ocevent.ocevents" version="0.0.1">
   <name>Live</name>
   <description>Live Eventmanager</description>
   <author email="chh_rahul@live.com" href="http://softweavertech.com">Rahul Chhabra</author>
   <content src="index.html" />
   <allow-navigation href="*" />
   <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
   <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
   <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
   <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
   <icon src="icons/iphone_57x57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
   <icon src="icons/iphone_72x72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
   <icon src="icons/iphone_76x76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
   <icon src="icons/iphone_120x120.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
   <icon src="icons/iphone_152x152.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
   <icon src="icons/iphone_180x180.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />
   <icon src="icons/LiveIcon.png" gap:platform="android" />
   <!--splash src="icons/screen.png" gap:platform="android" /-->
   <!--icon src="icons/OCEM4-Android_57.png" gap:platform="android" /-->
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" />
   <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="pgb" />
   <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" source="npm">
      <param name="URL_SCHEME" value="live" />
   </gap:plugin>
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
   <!--gap:plugin name="com.hutchind.cordova.plugins.streamingmedia" spec="0.1.3" source="pgb" /-->
   <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="pgb" />
   <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="pgb" />
   <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="pgb" />
   <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="pgb" />
   <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIStatusBarHidden">
      <true />
   </gap:config-file>
   <platform name="android">
      <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->
      <splash src="icons/screen_640x960.png" density="land-hdpi" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_640x960.png" density="land-ldpi" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_640x960.png" density="land-mdpi" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_640x960.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_640x960.png" density="port-hdpi" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_640x960.png" density="port-ldpi" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_640x960.png" density="port-mdpi" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_640x960.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
   </platform>
   <platform name="ios">
      <!-- images are determined by width and height. The following are supported -->
      <splash src="icons/screen_320x480.png" width="320" height="480" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_640x960.png" width="640" height="960" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_768x1024.png" width="768" height="1024" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_1536x2048.png" width="1536" height="2048" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_1024x768.png" width="1024" height="768" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_2048x1536.png" width="2048" height="1536" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_640x1136.png" width="640" height="1136" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_750x1334.png" width="750" height="1334" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_1242x2208.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
      <splash src="icons/screen_2208x1242.png" width="2208" height="1242" />
   </platform>
   <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance">
      <false />
   </gap:config-file>
   <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
   <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
   <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
   <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
   <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
   <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
   <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
   <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="15" />
   <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
</widget>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround I've made.

Since you're running the Iframe inside a Cordova container, you can modify it's contents.

The idea is to-

1. "listen" to the iframe page loaded events
2. Search for the urls you wish to open outside cordova, then backup-and-remove the href property from the html elements inside the iframe.
3. Instead of the href property, we assign 'onclick' listeners which will "postMessage" to the parent iFrame container (your Cordova webpage probably), where you can handle the click-event and the url link as you see fit, such as opening it via the InAppBrowserPlugin.

And here's the implementation:

```
// Making sure we're in Cordova environment
if(window['cordova']) {
    const linksToModify = [
      // *** Modify *** to the correct selector for your IFrame href elemenets you wish to affect, here's an example (You can put multiple elements here):
      yourIframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector('#html_element > iframe').contentWindow.document.querySelector('body > a:nth-child(1)'),
    ];

    // Once we have a reference to the elements containing the href urls we remove their href property
    // Instead the href property, we "postMessage" to your cordova/phonegap container, where you can handle the href string as you see fit.
    for(let el of linksToModify) {
      let theHref = el.getAttribute('href');
      if(theHref == null) continue;
      try {
        el.removeAttribute('href');
      } catch(_) {}
      try {
        el.removeAttribute('target');
      } catch(_) {}
      // Notify parent iframe of the click instead of opening the url in browser
      el.setAttribute('onclick', "parent.postMessage({type:'fromIframe',event:'open',link:'" + theHref + "'},'*');")
    }
}
```

Modify the element selector for your specific iframe elements which contain href attributes.
Tip-You might want to run the code block after page load under a timer with retries, In my case, I used 15 max retries (1 per second).
Once the element is found and the href attributes are removed, you can cancel the timer of course.

Afterwards, add the listener in the parent container (your Cordova webpage js code):

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(thePostedMessage) {
    /// Handle link as you wish, it's in "thePostedMessage" argument.
}
```